# JSON web service to access all files a user has access to using Javascript. (Liferay 7)

Tags: javascript, json, liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to **use the JSON web service API through Javascript to get all the files from the Documents Library that a user has access to**, which I attempted to use:

```
Liferay.Service(
    '/dlfileentry/get-group-file-entries',
    {
        groupId: gId,
        userId: userId,
        rootFolderId: 0,
        start: 0,
        end: 300,
        '-obc': ''
    },
    function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    }
);
```

However, this call only retrieves the files that were uploaded by that specific user, which is not what I want. **Is there another way that would achieve retrieving all the documents that a specific user has access to view?**

I thought about using the web service call:

```
Liferay.Service(
    '/assetentry/get-entries',
    {
    entryQuery: 
    },
    function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    }
);
```

However, I don't know if this would achieve a similar result and I don't know how to pass an `AssetEntryQuery` object into the `entryQuery` parameter.

**UPDATE:** A second way to do this (clearly not the best way) would be to grab all the subfolderIds through using `/dlfolder/get-subfolder-ids` and then iterate through each folder using `/dlapp/get-file-entries` including the root and saving those files like so:

```
var files = [];

Liferay.Service(
    '/group/get-user-sites-groups',
    function(obj) {
        var result;
        for(var i= 0; i< obj.length; i++)
        {
            result = obj[i].groupId;

            Liferay.Service(
            '/dlfolder/get-subfolder-ids',
            {
                groupId: result,
                folderId: 0,
                recurse: true
            },
            function(subIds) 
            {
                var folders = subIds;
                folders.unshift(0);
                for(var i=0; i< folders.length; i++)
                {
                    Liferay.Service(
                    '/dlapp/get-file-entries',
                    {
                        repositoryId: result,
                        folderId: folders.pop()
                    },
                    function(object) {

                        if(object.length > 0)
                        {
                            files=files.concat(object);                         
                        }
                    });
                }
            });



        }
    });
```

But as you can imagine, this means call a web service per folder which as is sounds seems highly inefficient. What is another way to do this using web services?

Comment: You can use `/dlapp/get-file-entries` (`repositoryId`, `folderId`), which internally checks for the `VIEW` permission over folder.

Comment: @ParkashKumar That works if I just wanted the files of one folder, but is there an elegant way to retrieve the files in the subfolders on that file and so on like the way `/dlfileentry/get-group-file-entries` retrieves all the files?

Comment: Well, you can pass `0` for `folderId`, which is the `folderId` of root / home.

Comment: You can yourself check all the available services using: `http://IP:PORT/api/jsonws` (Replace IP:PORT with your server's respectively) and search for `DLApp`.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Yeah, you can pass 0 into `folderId`, however, it will just return the files that are located in the root folder. If there are any folders in root, it wouldn't return any files that were in that folder, you would have to retrieve the folderIds of all the subfolders and recursively call the `/dlapp/get-file-entries` web service for all those folders to get all those files, which I can do, but I think that would be too many service calls for hundreds of folders and their subfolders. I've look in `api/jsonws` before many times, I was hoping there was something I might have missed.

Comment: Obviously, this Liferay service doesn't populate the nested folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a web service that will return all the files that a user has access to. By using `'/assetentry/get-entries'` with an empty entryQuery `{}` it'll return all the files that pass the permission check.

```
Liferay.Service(
        '/assetentry/get-entries',
        {
            entryQuery: {}
        },
        function(object) {
            console.log('/assetentry/get-entries empty');
            console.log(object);
        }
);
```

If you want to limit it to a groupId or some other parameter, you'd add an array with those conditions like so into the entryQuery parameter:

```
entryQuery: {"classNameIds":[10007],"groupIds":[10182]}
```

This solution is just what I needed.